# Can't get location right using Swift

Tags: swift, location, locationmanager

So, I am trying to get my Location inside a function of my ViewController.swift.

The Code I use works when i try it like this:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation


class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var manager : CLLocationManager!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        manager = CLLocationManager()
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
        manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

        var locValue : CLLocationCoordinate2D
        locValue = manager.location.coordinate
        println("Coordinates = \(locValue.longitude) + \(locValue.latitude)")
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
```

But what I am trying to do is get it while pressing a button which toggles a function:

```
var manager : CLLocationManager!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        manager = CLLocationManager()
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
        manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        var locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location.coordinate
        println("locations = \(locValue.longitude) \(locValue.latitude)")
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    @IBAction func refresh() {
        getWeatherData()
        refreshButton.hidden = true
        acitivityIndicatorView.hidden = false
        acitivityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       }

        func getWeatherData() -> Void {

 func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
                var locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location.coordinate
                println("locations = \(locValue.longitude) \(locValue.latitude)")
                manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
```

While using a breakpoint i realized it gets to func locationManager but it jumps to the end of my getweatherdata() function.

I can't see why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is not possible. Inly thing you can do is call `manager.startUpdatingLocation()` inside `refresh()` and wait till `didUpdateLocations` get called with the updated location data.

```
@IBAction func refresh() {
    manager.startUpdatingLocation() 
    refreshButton.hidden = true
    acitivityIndicatorView.hidden = false
    activityIndicatorView.hidesWhenStopped = true
    acitivityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    var locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location.coordinate
    println("locations = \(locValue.longitude) \(locValue.latitude)")
    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    refreshButton.hidden = false
    acitivityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()

}
```

Comment: I think you forgot to change getWeatherData() by manager.startUpdatingLocation() in refresh function :)

Comment: Wow, thank you!
I didn't even think about it, but yeah it makes sense. It all works now, thanks!